# UIBarButton title doesn't get displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have added a UIBarButton. However, i am not able to display a title.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 30, 30)];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

self.navigationController.visibleViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customItem;
```

I tried the following:

```
button.title =@"Title";
```

and

```
customItem.title=@"title";
```

Comment: No clue why this is down voted without an explanation :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do so much stuff like you are doing,Just do like:

```
UIBarButtonItem *customItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=customItem;
```

Hope it helps....:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIButton setTitle:forState:` instead accessing property. Also you should create button with method `[UIButton buttonWithType:<#(UIButtonType)#>]` instead of `UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 30, 30)];`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Title"
                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                            target:self
                            action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:)];
self.navigationController.visibleViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customItem;
```